# ;# without resetting

Tags: code-golf, string

`;#` is a very simple language. It has 2 commands:

- `;` will increment the accumulator
- `#` outputs the accumulator modulo 127, and then resets the accumulator

`;$` is also very simple and is very similar (and also does not yet exist). It has 2 commands:

- `;` will increment the accumulator
- `$` outputs the accumulator modulo 127. However, it does not reset the accumulator.

## Challenge

Create a program that will convert `;#` code to `;$` code. That is, given input `a` using standard methods, output he shortest `b` such that `a` in `;#` outputs the same thing as `b` in `;$`. The input will only contain the characters `';'` and `'#'`. The input will not have trailing semicolons. That is, it will match the regex `(;*#)+`. This also means input will not be blank. Note that `;;;;##` is possible (equivalent to `ord(4) ord(0)`).

## Examples

```
;# code -> ;$ code
;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;# -> ;;;;;;;;;;$;;$
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;# -> ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;# -> ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;;;;;$$;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$ (Hello, World!)
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this, because there are too many `;#` questions going around. They're not very interesting.

Comment: @isaacg Ah. Thanks for your input. I'll try to keep my challenges more original next time though do note that this was one of the earlier `;#` challenges; it was the first one after the compiler and the transpiler IIRC.

Comment: Is the `;#` input shortest one?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
ṣ”#L€ṙ-I%127”;ẋp”$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGuYq@zxqWvNw50xdT1VDI3OggPXDXd0FQFrl////1ihAGYQB)

#### How it works

```
ṣ”#L€ṙ-I%127”;ẋp”$  Main link. Argument: s (string)

ṣ”#L€               Split s at hashes. Take the length of each resulting chunk.
     ṙ-             Rotate the result -1 units to the left / 1 unit to the right.
                    Since s won't have trailing semicola, the length of the last
                    chunk will be 0. Rotating moves this 0 to the beginning.
       I            Increments; take all forward differences. Because of the 0 we
                    removed to the beginning, the first forward difference will be
                    the length of the first chunk.
        %127        Take the differences modulo 127. In Python, `n % d' is either 0
                    or has the same sign as d, so this reports how many semicola
                    are needed to get from one code point to the next one.
            ”;ẋ     Repeat ';' k times, for each modulus k.
               p”$  Take the Cartesian product with "$", appending '$' to each run
                    of semicola.
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/;*#/g,s=>';'.repeat((127-a+(a=s.length))%127)+'$',a=1)
```

#### Examples

```js
let f =

s=>s.replace(/;*#/g,s=>';'.repeat((127-a+(a=s.length))%127)+'$',a=1)

console.log(f(";;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;#"))
console.log(f(";;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;#"))
console.log(f(";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;#"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 99 bytes

```php
while(~$c=a^$argn[$p++])j^$c?r^$c?:$a=-$b*$b=print str_repeat(";",(127+$a%127)%127)."$":$b+=!!++$a;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 37 bytes

```
[:;';$'<@#~1,.~127|2-~/\0,=&'#'#;._2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulEG1lrW6tom7joFxnqKNXZ2hkXmOkW6cfY6Bjq6aurK5srRdvFMvFlZqcka@QpqBuDQfK1khAWf3/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>101</s> <s>100</s> <s>97</s> 85 bytes

*1 bytes saved thanks to @WheatWizard*

```python
def t(c,s=0):
 for x in map(len,c.split('#')[:-1]):print(end=';'*((x-s)%127)+'$');s=x
```

Comment: You can drop the space between `)` and `for`

Comment: @WheatWizard thanks

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 52 bytes

```
^
##
#
127$*;$
^;+\$;+\$|(;+)(?<=\$\1(;{127})?\$\1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfx6WszKXMZWhkrqJlrcIVZ60dowLCNRrW2poa9ja2MSoxhhrW1UAFtZr2II4m1///1nCgbI0ElLmsUYAyFjHygbI1PQB9bBn2lpFqn/JAuX5Qh8poKiPXEmUA) Includes test suite. Explanation: 127 is added to each `#` to make the subtraction modulo 127 easier; the `#`s are changed to `$` at the same time. The subtraction itself is handled by the lookbehind `(?<=\$\1(;{127})?\$\1)` which ensures that we subtract either the number of `;`s between the previous two `#`s (which handles the case when there are more `;`s) or 127 fewer than that number (which handles the case when there are fewer `;`s and they need to wrap past 127). A lookbehind is used so that all the replacements can be calculated in one pass. In order for there always to be two previous `#`s, two extra `#`s are temporarily prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 65 bytes

```perl
s/(;*)#/$b=($q+$b)%127;';'x($q+=(($q=length$1)<$b)*127-$b).'$'/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VXbCsIwDH33KwKN7CJbVRAf4vwXJ3UbzK2uFfx6awXx/qCbbCIeSkvISZOm5VSKKp8Yo7hLvsc4xpGLmwHGXn80npJDzu5oR66do1wUiU5x5M2s37f@wK6hgw5PhCHFIfQ5J0u0uwxJVlmhkRMwSEUlYFVWoIXSWZHAepvrTOYClgsllKEzGF2BQTCHi4l29OgG7JF1YraP@9rqg7VSL2uzOb@b7N18rKvqv7or/1dWN8kT@WugYS95EZtqbBcCjZ@Ow44O0uEf1/je96XUWVkoE8gD)